# How to set up MS Application Insight if there are multiple alias for one application?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have an application, for example called sample and my domain is mydomain.com.

I put this application under Default Web Site. So user can access it by:

```
mydomain.com/sample
```

I also created a separate site on the same IIS and bind it with a sub domain so user can also access it by:

```
sample.mydomain.com
```

Physically there is only one folder "Sample" under Default Web Site. However, the AI online does not showing any data.

When I run Get-WebApplicationMonitoringStatus, it shows two Display Name as Sample but pointing to WebApplications(actually there is only one).

Display Name: Sample
WebApplication: Default Web Site/Sample
......

Display Name: Sample
WebAppliction: Sample

That seems causing problem for AI to collect data properly. I also see an Warning in Event Viewer as:Two applications with the same display name have been detected. Monitoring for the applications has been stopped. Ensure that the display names are unique before you proceed.

So, I am wondering what is the best monitoring solution for this case?

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed from MS. That is not supported by MMA at this point. We have to restructure our site to avoid multiple websites pointing to the same physical folder.